# CXF - Wsdl2Java enable to access to xml.xsd

Tags: eclipse, cxf, wsdl2java

I am trying to set up a SOAP Web Service with Eclipse and CXF, using the contract first approach. I already generated the wsdl file and it is correct. When I am using the CXF Wsdl2Java to generate the SOAP Web Service, I got the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference: 
            Failed to read schema document 'xml.xsd', because 'file' access is not allowed 
            due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
```

Any help? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys. I found the solution.
If it does not exist, create a file named `jaxp.properties` under `%JRE_HOME%/lib` and then write the following line in it:

```
javax.xml.accessExternalSchema = all
```

Comment: It would be generally more acceptable to add this as a VM argument if possible `-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=ALL `